# How to continue setting up Moto E phone when setup is stuck in a loop?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google-account, setup-wizard

I have a 2nd generation Moto E phone running Lollipop. As a family member set a lock screen and forgot the password, I did a factory reset by selecting "Power" + "Down Arrow". Now, it is giving the initial Motorola setup screen. When I go through these settings, it keeps looping. It asks me to set the Privacy Settings. Then it asks me to enter my Google Account phone number and password. After entering this, it returns to asking me to enter the privacy settings. And then asks for the Google Account details again. It is in an endless loop. How can I setup the Moto E phone and get it out of this loop?

Comment: Can we have a screenshoot (photo) of that screen?

Comment: Sounds like you are in a FRP (Factory Reset Protection) loop, not entering the correct credentials... You must enter the email and password for the Gmail account that was active on the phone prior to the reset, otherwise as esQmo stated, some screenshots would be nice.